# Bootstrap 3 submit Button not working in Android mobile Chrome broswer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Now I am struggling in mid of somewhere ... I can't find solution even I spend hours with alternative methods... Expecting tips ...
My problem is..
Users can not click submit button (bootstrap3) on mobile device especially in android  but it is working on PC/laptop well, I don't know where is my mistake even after done lot of changes.

There is another 2 btn in same modal, that's working fine...

In my page I am using model form for login, code as shown in below...

```
 <div class="modal-body borderpadding3px">
           <!-- login form -->
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 div_align_center">
    <form id="login" name="login" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend style="border:none;"></legend>

    <div class="form-group div_align_left">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Login Email Id</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
          <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your registered email id" type="email">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Prepended text-->
    <div class="form-group div_align_left">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label div_align_left" for="pwd">Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
          <input id="pwd" name="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group div_align_left">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-xs-1 col-sm-1" for="submit"></label>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-10">
        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">LOG IN</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 div_align_right">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="forgotpwd();" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs margin-top-20"> Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>

       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 borderBottom">
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="row margin-top-10">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin-bottom-10 div_align_center">
     <a href="new_user_register.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> New user? Register</a>
     </div>
     </div>
    </form>
     </div> 
     </div>

           <!-- login form ends -->
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is not allowed for mobile sizing using `col-xs-*` classes

Change your button code to this and it will work - then style it as you want

Note how I've used class `col-xs-12` so your buttons are now on their own lines on mobile devices

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-10 col-xs-12"><!-- added col-xs-12 -->
    <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">LOG IN</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 div_align_right"><!-- added col-xs-12 -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="forgotpwd();" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs margin-top-20"> Forgot Password?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks lot sir, I fixed my problem ... the culprit is *-XS (very small device), Just I removed that , its working fine... but I wonder why bootstrap keeping *-XS....

Comment: I know this is an ancient answer, but is there any documentation on this?  I can't find anything. In my experimenting it appears that col-xs-## completely blocks form submits on Android.  This includes both `<button>` and `<input>` submit types.  I really like my layout as it is and don't want to bump the button to a new line on mobile. I don't understand your multiple `col` classes on the same div above.

Comment: *Update*: The col-xs itself wasn't the problem. It was an inconsistent mix of col-xs and col-sm.  I was using col-sm in general but I changed the `div` surrounding the submit button to col-xs to prevent a line break.  I was able to fix this by filling in the missing col-xs values in the other divs.  So now all divs in the row account for all 12 bootstrap columns in both col-sm and col-xs sizings.  Hope this helps somebody...